# In gridview, updatepanel is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

**html code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridprodlist" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No record" Width="100%">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit&lt;br/&gt;Delete&lt;br/&gt;Disable">
<ItemTemplate>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
     <tr>
        <td valign="top">
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel100" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkdis" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkdis_CheckedChanged" ValidationGroup='<%# Eval("pid") %>' Text="Disable" />
            </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
```

**.cs code**

```
protected void chkdis_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkdis = (CheckBox)sender;
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(((CheckBox)sender).ValidationGroup);

    if (chkdis.Checked == true)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

I had put updatepanel inside the gridview but still On click of my checkbox my page get refresh.
what should i do?
I dont want my page to get refresh

Comment: I don't know what the default is but you are missing the property `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to register this `CheckBox` as async-postback control from codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     gridprodlist.DataBound += GridprodList_DataBound;
}  

private void GridprodList_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
    foreach(GridViewRow row in gridprodlist.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkdis = (CheckBox) row.FindControl("chkdis");
        sm.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(chkdis);
    }
}
```

---

> its working for first time only but on second time again my page gets
>   refresh

Then try to use `RowCreated` which is triggered on every postback for every row:

```
ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);

private void GridprodList_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chkdis = (CheckBox) e.Row.FindControl("chkdis");
        sm.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(chkdis);
    }
}
```

Comment: its working for first time only but on second time again my page gets refresh.......i had put my gridview in if(!ispostback){} on page load i think so because of ispostback its not working second time ......what should i do

Comment: @MiteshJain: Try to use  `RowCreated` instead. Edited my answer.

Comment: on instant click some of my check box is being checked and some of them are not get  checked what shall i do for that

Comment: @MiteshJain: Yes of course. **Edit** according to your last comment: i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: actually i was using both databound and rowcreated which used to consume more time now its working fine ..

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the UpdatePanel out of the GridView, and wrap the entire GridView in the UpdatePanel, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I dont want updatepanel outside the gridview as many controls are also there which i had not specified in this question

Comment: At least for debugging purposes,that might indicate whether that's the actual problem...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like this because **GridView is converted to table** while being rendered. The update panel is not certainly being added to each row on being rendered. So, the best way is to put the gridview inside the updatepanel.

Comment: but when i put update panel inside the datalist it works properly

Comment: Use JSON, in the <script> section, that is a better method. Create the table dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Move UpdatePanel to out of the GridView, and wrap the GridView in the UpdatePanel. If you still need postback on some controls then use, just before the closing tag of UpdatePanel.

```
<Triggers> 
<PostBackTriggers ControlId="YourControlId"/>
<Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```